# Smartest way to convert a list into a string

Tags: f#

If I have a list:

```
let list123 = [ 1; 2; 3 ]
```

what would be the most F#-approach to converting it into a string "[ 1; 2; 3 ]"? All questions I have found regarding list to string conversion, revolves around only taking the list elements, but I want the entire list expression.

Comment: Why is this closed as opinion-based? It doesn't make sense. The nature of the F# programming language makes it very common to ask for idiomatic ways to perform tasks. One will have to close most questions about F# if these questions aren't allowed. Reopen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're asking, but here goes:

```
let s = list123 |> Seq.map string |> String.concat "; " |> sprintf "[ %s ]"
```

EDIT

It has the drawback that an empty list becomes `[ ]` rather than `[]`, and this can be fixed e.g. by using a match similar to what FRocha does in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

As F# is a .NET language I don't see why `System.String.Join` is less F#-ish than anything else:

```
module List =
    let toString (lst: 'a list) = 
        match lst with
        | [] -> "[]"
        | _ -> sprintf "[ %s ]" (String.Join("; ", lst))
```

But if you insist doing it by your self in "real" F# it could be something like:

```
module List =
    let join lst =
        match lst with
        | [] -> ""
        | [ h ] -> h |> string
        | h::t -> 
            sprintf "%s" (t |> List.fold (fun res a -> sprintf "%s; %A" res a) (h |> string))

    let formatAsString prefix postfix lst = 
        match lst |> join with
        | "" -> sprintf "%s%s" prefix postfix
        | str -> sprintf "%s %s %s" prefix str postfix

    let toString lst = formatAsString "[" "]" lst

let empty = []
let one = [ 1 ]
let four = [ 1; 2; 3; 4 ]

printfn "%s" (empty |> List.toString)
printfn "%s" (one |> List.toString)
printfn "%s" (four |> List.toString)
```

outputs:

```
[]
[ 1 ]
[ 1; 2; 3; 4 ]
```

Comment: The pattern match isn't needed. `"[" + String.Join("; ", list123) + "]"` works.

Comment: @Daniel: It depends on if you want spaces after the start and before the end bracket and also want the empty list to be without spaces between the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Use the string function:

```
string list123 //val it : string = "[1; 2; 3]"
```

EDIT

Addressing the good point made by Bent Tranberg.

```
let inline listToString l = 
    match l with
    | [] -> "[]"
    | l ->
        (l |> List.head |> string |> (+) "[",List.tail l)
        ||> List.fold (fun acc elem -> acc + "; " + string elem) |> (+) <| "]"
```

Comment: I would not trust this to always return that exact string in future versions of F#, though I admit it's very unlikely to change for this particular very simple example. For other more complex examples, I definitely would not trust the formatting of the output to stay the same.

Comment: To understand what I mean, just try with [ 1 .. 100 ]